# .NET Core Geometry data type throws "The property 'City.Point' is of type 'Geometry' which is not supported by the current database provider

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm working on a .NET core web API application with SQL server

The goal here is that the user will pass his latitude & longitude and I have to find the nearest city to him.

In the database we have a table were we store a geography data type with city name and id.

Now I wanted to do below with .NET core EF

```
var nearestCity = db.Cities
    .OrderBy(c => c.Location.Distance(currentLocation))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

So to do that I have installed this package

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite
```

And in db context I added

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("connection string", x => x.UseNetTopologySuite());
```

Now this is the mapping after scaffolding

```
public partial class City
 {
    public City()
     {
     Districts = new HashSet<District>();
     Profile = new HashSet<Profile>();
     }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NameArabic { get; set; }
    public Geometry Point { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<District> Districts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Profiles> Profiles { get; set; }

}
```

Now whenever I try to access city table it throws this exception

```
"The property 'City.Point' is of type 'Geometry' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' 
attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'."}
```

I tried to change the Geometry to Point datatype still same issue.
Also I have tried to add this

```
entity.Property(e => e.Point).HasColumnType("geometry").HasColumnName("point");
```

How to solve this issue? And does geography data type is really supported by .NET core?
and what are the alternatives.

Even if I changed the data type in database to double as latitude & longitude
I couldn't find a built in function that will help me to calculate the distance between user and each city.

Here is the packages versions

```
microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver 5.0.7

microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver.nettopologysuite 5.0.7

microsoft.entityframeworkcore 5.0.7
```

Sql relationships
[image]

Comment: How did you designed your SQL Server table entities, could you please share?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Thank you for the reply , I have added the diagram with related tables. Sorry for the font it's too small

Comment: If you're talking about latitude and logitude, why are you trying to use the geo*metr*y type rather than the geo*graph*y one?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I thought of this too , But this is what get generated when I scaffold the db context. Even if I try to change Geometry to Geography I get 
(The type or namespace name 'Geography' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Just now I have installed the package System.Spatial and I used Geography instead of Geometry still same exception is thrown ("The property 'City.Point' is of type 'Geography' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' 
)

Comment: I am looking into the databse design and how the data in it looks like,